# Prove that $\frac{1}{\log_{2}{\pi}}+\frac{1}{\log_{\pi}{2}}> 2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

I have tried in many ways and i could not do it.

Comment: Can you prove that, in general, for $p$ and $q$ positive, $\frac{p}{q}+\frac{q}{p}\geq 2$?  Now, can you use log rules to relate the given LHS to the fractions $\frac{p}{q}$?

Comment: Find the relation with $f(x)=x+\dfrac1x$ and study the latter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remember that the sum of a positive number and its reciprocal is never less than 2. That is, $a + \dfrac{1}{a} \geq 2$. Equality happens when $a=1$.

In this case, notice that $log_{\pi} 2$ and $\log_2 \pi$ are reciprocals of each other. Hence, the conclusion.

Comment: thanks for the compliment!

Answer (score 0):

For *any* $a, b > 0$, $\log_a b = {1 \over \log_b a}$. Hence the original inequality will be shown if we can demonstrate that for arbitrary $x > 0, x \neq 1$ that

$$x + {1 \over x} > 2 \ \ \ \ \ \ - (*) $$

We have $x \neq 1$ as $\log_2 \pi \neq 1$.

The relation (*) is true by the AM-GM inequality, strict inequality holding precisely because $x \neq 1$:

$${1 \over 2} \left( x + {1 \over x} \right) > \sqrt{x\cdot{1 \over x}} = 1$$

Comment: Downvoter care to comment?

Comment: You should also add that since, for this case, $x\neq \dfrac{1}{x}$, the equality case doesn't hold and we get a strict inequality. p.s- I didn't downvote your answer. :)

Comment: Beautiful proof

Answer (score 0):

By the base change formula for logs,

$$\log_\pi 2 = \frac{1}{\log_2 \pi}.$$

Thus

$$\frac{1}{\log_2 \pi} + \frac{1}{\log_\pi 2} = \frac{1}{\log_2 \pi} + \log_2 \pi = \left(\sqrt{\frac{1}{\log_2 \pi}} - \sqrt{\log_2 \pi}\right)^2 + 2 > 2.$$

Comment: I like the way to establish the inequation.

Comment: Downvotes for all answerers who stepped on the toes of the hints (by Michael and Yves), and did not wait for the OP to attempt the problem using the hints.

Comment: I actually didn't see the hints they gave until you mentioned it. No problem, I'll delete my answer.

Comment: No, don't do it

Comment: Ok then, I'll leave it up.